# How to append further fields to select list item "Text" in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have:

```
ViewBag.StdLibraryId = new SelectList(db.StdLibrary, "Id", "Name",stdlibraryitem.StdLibraryId);
```

I want to append another column's value to the text output, so it would be something like

```
ViewBag.StdLibraryId = new SelectList(db.StdLibrary, "Id", Model.Name + "(" + model.Category.Name + ")", stdlibraryitem.StdLibraryId);
```

However, obviously the code above is wrong. Also I am tending to use Lambda expressions in my LINQ.

What should the code look like?

Huge thanks in advance.

EDIT

My new code:

```
            ViewBag.StdLibraryId = new SelectList(db.StdLibrary.Select(r=> new {Id = r.Id, Name= r.Name + "(" + r.StdSection.Name + ")"}), "Id", "Name", stdlibraryitem.StdLibraryId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just use an anonymous object in which you will make your concatenation.

```
var stdLibraryForCombo = db.StdLibrary
                         .Select(m => new {
                            Id = m.Id,
                            Name = m.Name + " (" + m.Category.Name + ")"
                         });
ViewBag.StdLibraryId = new SelectList(stdLibraryForCombo, "Id", "Name", stdlibraryitem.StdLibraryId);
```

Comment: Thanks, see edit. I think we were thinking along the same lines at the same time!! However I have another problem in that if category is null then I get nothing in "Name".

Comment: Basically I need "If Category is null then use '' rather than Category value"

Comment: Sorted=  Category ?? "". Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SamJolly Hmmm, rather `Category == null ? string.Empty : Category.Name`

Comment: @SamJolly it's just not the same. You used the coalesce operator, I used the ternary one, which seems to be more adapted here...